# Comma in cases? (Maths)

Tags: commas, grammatical-case

In maths we sometimes want to show that a quantity can obtain different values depending on what case we consider. We call this cases.

I cannot draw it here for you because LaTeX is not enabled here, but if you [click this link](http://en.wikibooks.org/wiki/LaTeX/Advanced_Mathematics#Using_aligned_braces_for_piecewise_functions) you will know what I am talking about. As can be seen in the link, commas are not used inside the "cases"-bracket. I think this looks nicer. But should one use commas? What is the correct thing to do here?

Comment: Can you post a picture of what they do and what you want?

Comment: Would this not have been better asked on Math.SE (where functions can be drawn correctly too)? This is a specialised Maths grammar, not English.

Comment: This has very little to do with English grammar and usage.

Answer (score 1):

The usual advice mathematicians give for writing math is to punctuate it as if it were normal English (or at least, to stay as close to the rules for normal English as is possible without sacrificing clarity). If you follow this advice, you should use commas.

If you look on page 4 of the [AMSLatex guide](http://www.fi.infn.it/pub/tex/doc/orig/amslatex/amsldoc.pdf), you will see that they do indeed use commas after the cases in their example. AMS is the *American Math Society,* and one assumes they know how to punctuate math.

Your example is from a wiki Latex manual, which anybody can contribute to. This section might easily have been written by people who don't know the rules for punctuating math.

Comment: Thanks for your comment @Peter. I have seen both (with and without commas) and I have to say that "with commas" makes more sense.